# PayPal IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS Upgrade Specific Class

Tags: php, paypal, https, postback, paypal-ipn

I've been successfully using the below PayPal Website Payment Pro class for years. I'm trying to upgrade it to meet PayPal's IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS requirements without success. Here's the class:

```
class paypal_website_payment_pro
{
public $API_USERNAME;
public $API_PASSWORD;
public $API_SIGNATURE;
public $API_ENDPOINT;
public $USE_PROXY;
public $PROXY_HOST;
public $PROXY_PORT;
public $PAYPAL_URL;
public $VERSION;
public $NVP_HEADER;

function __construct($API_USERNAME, $API_PASSWORD, $API_SIGNATURE, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT, $IS_ONLINE = TRUE, $USE_PROXY = FALSE, $VERSION = '57.0')
{
$this->API_USERNAME = $API_USERNAME;
$this->API_PASSWORD = $API_PASSWORD;
$this->API_SIGNATURE = $API_SIGNATURE;      
$this->API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';
$this->USE_PROXY = $USE_PROXY;
if($this->USE_PROXY == true)
{
$this->PROXY_HOST = $PROXY_HOST;
$this->PROXY_PORT = $PROXY_PORT;
}
else
{
$this->PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$this->PROXY_PORT = '808';
}
if($IS_ONLINE == FALSE)
{
$this->PAYPAL_URL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=';
}
else
{
$this->PAYPAL_URL = 'https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=';
}
$this->VERSION = $VERSION;
}

function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->API_ENDPOINT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
if($this->USE_PROXY)
{
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->PROXY_HOST.":".$this->PROXY_PORT); 
}
$nvpreq="METHOD=".urlencode($methodName)."&VERSION=".urlencode($this->VERSION)."&PWD=".urlencode($this->API_PASSWORD)."&USER=".urlencode($this->API_USERNAME)."&SIGNATURE=".urlencode($this->API_SIGNATURE).$nvpStr;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$nvpreq);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$nvpResArray=$this->deformatNVP($response);
$nvpReqArray=$this->deformatNVP($nvpreq);
$_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;
if (curl_errno($ch))
{
die("CURL send a error during perform operation: ".curl_errno($ch));
} 
else 
{
curl_close($ch);
}

return $nvpResArray;
}

function deformatNVP($nvpstr)
{

$intial=0;
$nvpArray = array();
while(strlen($nvpstr))
{
$keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'='); 
$valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr); 
$keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
$valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
$nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
$nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
}
return $nvpArray;
}

function __destruct() 
{

}
}
```

Here's the class in action:

```
require_once("paypalprocess.php");
$nvpstr='&PAYMENTACTION='.$paymentAction.'&IPADDRESS='.$ip_address.'&DESC='.$item_name.'&AMT='.$amount.'&CREDITCARDTYPE='.$creditCardType.'&ACCT='.$creditCardNumber.'&EXPDATE='.         $padDateMonth.$expDateYear.'&CVV2='.$cvv2Number.'&FIRSTNAME='.$firstName.'&LASTNAME='.$lastName.'&STREET='.$address1.'&STREET2='.$address2.'&CITY='.$city.'&STATE='.$state.'&ZIP='.$zip.'&COUNTRYCODE='.$countrycode.'&INVNUM='.$app_idpp.'&CUSTOM=Credit Card&CURRENCYCODE='.$currencyCode.$nvpRecurring;

$paypal_website_payment_pro = new paypal_website_payment_pro(USERNAME, PASSWORD, PAYPALKEY, '', '', TRUE, FALSE );

$resArray = $paypal_website_payment_pro->hash_call($methodToCall,$nvpstr);

$ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

if($ack!="SUCCESS")
{
// error stuff
}
else
{
// success stuff
}
```

I've attempted to change the API_ENDPOINT to: https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and added necessary curl_setopt parameters (see below). PayPal says I still need to postback to HTTPS. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Updated class:

```
<?php
class paypal_website_payment_pro
{
public $API_USERNAME;
public $API_PASSWORD;
public $API_SIGNATURE;
public $API_ENDPOINT;
public $USE_PROXY;
public $PROXY_HOST;
public $PROXY_PORT;
public $PAYPAL_URL;
public $VERSION;
public $NVP_HEADER;

function __construct($API_USERNAME, $API_PASSWORD, $API_SIGNATURE, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT, $IS_ONLINE = TRUE, $USE_PROXY = FALSE, $VERSION = '57.0')
{
$this->API_USERNAME = $API_USERNAME;
$this->API_PASSWORD = $API_PASSWORD;
$this->API_SIGNATURE = $API_SIGNATURE;      
$this->API_ENDPOINT = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$this->USE_PROXY = $USE_PROXY;
if($this->USE_PROXY == true)
{
$this->PROXY_HOST = $PROXY_HOST;
$this->PROXY_PORT = $PROXY_PORT;
}
else
{
$this->PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$this->PROXY_PORT = '808';
}
if($IS_ONLINE == FALSE)
{
$this->PAYPAL_URL = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=';
}
else
{
$this->PAYPAL_URL = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=';
}
$this->VERSION = $VERSION;
}

function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->API_ENDPOINT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
if($this->USE_PROXY)
{
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->PROXY_HOST.":".$this->PROXY_PORT); 
}
$nvpreq="METHOD=".urlencode($methodName)."&VERSION=".urlencode($this->VERSION)."&PWD=".urlencode($this->API_PASSWORD)."&USER=".urlencode($this->API_USERNAME)."&SIGNATURE=".urlencode($this->API_SIGNATURE).$nvpStr;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$nvpreq);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$nvpResArray=$this->deformatNVP($response);
$nvpReqArray=$this->deformatNVP($nvpreq);
$_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;
if (curl_errno($ch))
{
die("CURL send a error during perform operation: ".curl_errno($ch));
} 
else 
{
curl_close($ch);
}

return $nvpResArray;
}

function deformatNVP($nvpstr)
{

$intial=0;
$nvpArray = array();
while(strlen($nvpstr))
{
$keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'='); 
$valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr); 
$keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
$valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
$nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
$nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
}
return $nvpArray;
}

function __destruct() 
{

}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using port 443 instead of 808?

Comment: $USE_PROXY is false.